# Key board problems? (QWERTY)

Tags: 14.04, keyboard, lts

When I try use shift and the @ key it gives me this >  "

P.S for  some reason if I shift and press 2 I get @
also I tried setting keyboard layout to default

Comment: I hope I was able to explain my issue correctly :/

Comment: Can you tell us what language your keyboard is set to use? It's in the **System Settings > Text Entry** tab, on the left.

Comment: @EricPower Those keys are UK I believe.

Comment: I'm using cinnamon desktop

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have set the keyboard to UK.

Open System Settings -> Region And Language -> Input Sources -> And select US

[image]

If you can't see English US, click + and search for it:

[image]